# Simple client server with loop messaging

Tags: java, sockets

I am trying to implement a simple client server program that will continuously exchange messages until client decides to stop. I found many tutorials on this topic, however I am struggling with implementing the loop correctly. The server processes the first request but does not process the others.

It is probably some silly mistake so please excuse me for asking such basic question - I am new to sockets. I would be glad for any help. I provide all the code (based on some example that I found):

Client:

```
public class Client {
    public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {

        talkWithServer();
    }

    private static void talkWithServer() throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        String sentence;
        String serverResponse;
        BufferedReader brClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 9000);
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader brServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

        while(true) {
            sentence = brClient.readLine();
            out.writeBytes(sentence + '\n');
            serverResponse = brServer.readLine();
            System.out.println(serverResponse);

            if (serverResponse.contains("<BYE>")) {
                break;
            }
        }

        clientSocket.close();
    }
}
```

Server:

```
public class Server {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        String clientSentence;
        ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(9000);

        Protocol protocol = new Protocol();

        while (true) {
            Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
            BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
            DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(
                    connectionSocket.getOutputStream());

            clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();

            String response = protocol.processInput(clientSentence);

            outToClient.writeBytes(response + '\n');
        }
    }
}
```

Protocol:

```
public class Protocol {

    public String processInput(String theInput) {
        String theOutput = "> " + theInput;


        return theOutput;
    }
}
```

I simplified the example for sake of easier debugging. Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is line "Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();"
If I remember right, this will try to accept new client everytime, and since you are connecting just one, it will wait on that line forever in second iteration.
I suggest you paste that line before the while loop.

Comment: You nailed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
while (true) {

        BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
        DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(
                connectionSocket.getOutputStream());

        clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();
        String response = protocol.processInput(clientSentence);

        outToClient.writeBytes(response + '\n');
        outToClient.flush();

    }
```